# Problem in extracting coefficients of regression models of rolling regression

Tags: r

I have two data frames. One data frame have 427 dependent variables while other data frame have 3 independent variables. Both set of variables have 204 observations. I want to regress these three independent variables over all dependent variables simultaneously. I am using a rolling window of 18 months. I am using roll_regres.fit function. To get intercept i have combined a variable with series of 1's in independent variables. But when i run these models. I do not get any results. If a run without adding 1 I get the results but do not get intercept results. The data is in matrix form as required.

```
x<-cbind(1,bse_fama_mat[,1:3])
ys<-bse_fama_mat[,-1:-3,drop=FALSE]
## Extracting Regression coefficients
model_intercept<-apply(ys,2,function(y) roll_regres.fit(x=x,y=y,width = 18)$coefs[,1])
model_smb<-apply(ys,2,function(y) roll_regres.fit(x=x,y=y,width = 18)$coefs[,2])
model_hml<-apply(ys,2,function(y) roll_regres.fit(x=x,y=y,width = 18)$coefs[,3])
model_rm<-apply(ys,2,function(y) roll_regres.fit(x=x,y=y,width = 18)$coefs[,4])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is right. Try check all the inputs files are in matrix form. And for multiple regression order matters. You can also use roll_lm() in library roll.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor point. Your code runs the same set of models multiple times. Every time, the code picks up a set of coefficient, it runs the whole set of models again. I think you might only need to run it once and pick up the coefficients from those models later.

```
x<-cbind(1,bse_fama_mat[,1:3])
ys<-bse_fama_mat[,-1:-3,drop=FALSE]
## Extracting Regression coefficients
models<-apply(ys,2,function(y) roll_regres.fit(x=x,y=y, width = 18))
```

All your coefficients will be saved in the `models` list. Then, it is a matter of working out how to get those coefficient out with something like: 
`as.matrix(models$yvariable$coefs)[,1]`,  `as.matrix(models$yvariable$coefs)[, 2]`, ...